# TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be string, not tuple

Tags: python, date, datetime, strptime

I am writing a python code for accepting user input for a date:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
time_input = str(raw_input("Please enter the time in HH:MM:SS format: "))
current_date = str(raw_input("Please enter the date in YYYY/MM/DD format:"))
selected_time = datetime.strptime((current_date, time_input),"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
print "Time selected: ",selected_time
```

I am getting an error  on this line:
`selected_time = datetime.strptime((current_date, time_input),"%Y/%m/%d  %H:%
M:%S.%f")`

> TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be string, not tuple

Comment: Briefly: multiple arguments are not automatically concatenated.

Answer (score 1):

as the error indicates

> TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be string, not tuple

```
selected_time = datetime.strptime((current_date, time_input),"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

The first argument is supposed to be a string but you are passing `(current_date, time_input)` which is a tuple.

Since you are accepting input separately for time and date, you can join them using `'%s %s' % (current_date, time_input)` and then pass it to `datetime.strptime` as follows

```
selected_time = datetime.strptime( 
     '%s %s' % (current_date, time_input), # first argument is now a string
      "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f",
)
```

Comment: I have tried with your solution but it is giving me another error AttributeError: 'method_descriptor' object has no attribute 'strptime'

Comment: Thanks for your help it is working now.Below is the corrected code   selected_time = datetime.strptime('%s %s'%(current_date, time_input),"%Y/%m/%d  %H:%M:%S")